# Do not accept externally created session identifiers

Tags: php

hoe we can stop to accept externally created session identifiers..

thanks

Comment: What do you mean externally created?

Comment: `session_name()` can set the name of a session... http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php

Comment: mins how to solve the problem......
Vulnerable URL: http://server.com/admin/secure/login.php
Remediation Tasks: Do not accept externally created session identifiers...

The following may require user attention:

POST /admin/secure/login.php
Cookie:PHPSESSID=e3f0349527d740441be206cd9e6d6c70


Referer:http://server.com/admin/secure/login.php

Host:server.com

Pragma:no-cache

Connection:Keep-Alive

txt_userid=election&txt_pass=b19dcb1f79a5ed253217bb281ce6f1a9&check_page=84645f3a58c356c1c7e867485091e566&login=Login

Reasoning:
One or more session identifiers were not updated in the response.

Comment: I don't think there is anyway that someone else from the external site can create session on your site..
Correct me if I am wrong. (or i just don't understand your question correctly)

Comment: i store the userid,login time in session  & flag=md5(logintime.userid) in database  at time of login ... and check md5(session_logintime.session_userid) with detabase flag value in every page...i dont know that anyone else from the external site can creat session in my site..

Answer (score 3):

If people pass in their own session identifier it will only work if it's a valid one anyways. You are already protected against this.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure sessions are only started from a cookie.
- Use session_regenerate_id() when adding/updating auth info
- Add an internal check that compares a hash made of the session_id, remote_addr and user_agent to the currently stored hash (inside your session data), eg:

  session_start();
  if (empty($_SESSION['auth_hash'])) {
      // new visitor
      $_SESSION['auth_hash'] = sha1(session_id() . 'SECRET_STRING' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
  }
  if ($_SESSION['auth_hash'] != sha1(session_id() . 'SECRET_STRING' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
      // invalid user / mitm-attack
      session_destroy();
      // display login or so
  }
- after adding/updating auth info, eg:

  session_regenerate_id();
  $_SESSION['auth_hash'] = sha1(session_id() . 'SECRET_STRING' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

@Daniel: This is NOT true, assigning your own value to a session cookie WILL create that session, and when that session already exists, WILL use that session. If measures like I suggested above are nog used, session takeovers and mitm attacks are possible...

Comment: Possible inaccuracies in my answer can more than likely be attributed to the fact that the question is horribly phrased. The only thing I ever claimed is that PHP will only assign existing data to your session if you can provide an existing, valid session id. That is correct.

Comment: +1 for session_regenerate_id though I would add to use it when changing 'levels' of access. So if a user logs in, regenerate. If they log out, regenerate.

Comment: @Daniel True, I guess I wasn't clear on what your awnser was saying.

Comment: @Narcissus In case of logout, it's better to destroy the session data, after wich the session_id doesn't have the significance it had when the user was logged in, and a regenerate isn't really necessary